# Click Event of a button to fire defined inside a listbox item placed at resources.xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have created a style for a listbox item which shows up the button. I can't fire the click event of a button as the style is kept in resources.xaml. How to fire the click event of a button?

I am setting the command property of a button :

```
<Button x:Name="image"  Grid.Column="9" Margin="4 0 4 0" Style="{StaticResource LedgerDeleteIcon}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

and in the usercontrol where i applying this style to a listbox, i am defining a delegate command :

public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand{ get; private set; }

and in constructor of the user control:

```
   this.DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(click_DeleteBn);


private void click_DeleteBn(object args)
{

}
```

But it doesn't fire am i doing anytinh wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Silverlight 4 the best way to do this is to bind the Button `Command` property to an implementation of `ICommand`.